# Does fixed point iteration converges in a second type Fredhom Equation?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, functional-equations

If I have a functional equation of the form $y=Uy+x$ where U is an integral operation and $x$ and $y$ functions. Do, in general, the sequence defined by $y_{n+1}=Uy_{n}+x$ converges to a solution of the equation?